# Can't locate file context.getDir("data", ...) in Android

Tags: android, file, directory

I have a db located at

`ctx.getApplicationContext().getDir("data", 0) + "/" + "db.db4o";`

How can I browse this file with an file manager or via USB? I can't seem to find it :<

Answer (score 0):

Browse with file manager, or USB, what does that mean? You can access the data directory, through a file manager, only if you are on a rooted device or an emulator.

Your application specific file are not directly stored in the data directory, but

data/data/your_package_name

Comment: On a device, you don't have access to read the data directory. Try an emulator, or a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

you could create an "asset" folder into your android project and put it there. Before that you can try with this:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("db.db4o");
```

And convert "is" if is necessary.

Regards